# What is the get special method doing in this class decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working through the Python Cookbook.

The following code defines decorators as classes:

```
import types
from functools import wraps

class Profiled:
    def __init__(self, func):
        wraps(func)(self)
        self.ncalls = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ncalls += 1
        return self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return types.MethodType(self, instance)

# Example

@Profiled
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

class Spam:
    @Profiled
    def bar(self, x):
        print(self, x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(add(2,3))
    print(add(4,5))
    print('ncalls:', add.ncalls)

    s = Spam()
    s.bar(1)
    s.bar(2)
    s.bar(3)
    print('ncalls:', Spam.bar.ncalls)
```

yields:

```
5
9
ncalls: 2
<__main__.Spam object at 0x1187d0828> 1
<__main__.Spam object at 0x1187d0828> 2
<__main__.Spam object at 0x1187d0828> 3
ncalls: 3
```

It makes sense to me how the Profiled class is decorating these functions, however, I'm struggling to understand what purpose the Profiled __ get __ method serves and why it is needed?

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

`Profiled` is a class that defines a descriptor object, i.e., it defines `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__`.

Fundamentally, a descriptor is any python type that implements any combination of `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__`.

These will get invoked when you do `some_object.some_attribute`, `some_object.some_attribute = value`, and `del some_object.some_attribute` where `some_attribute` is a descriptor on `some_object.__class__`.

You can read about [the descriptor protocol here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).

It is also worth going through [Descriptors HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Essentially, this `__get__` allows your decorator to act like a method (function objects *are descriptors!* and the way that methods get bound to instances is that `FunctionType.__get__` does essentially what is written in that `Profiled.__get__`)

Comment: thanks juanpa, i'm confused about when _ _get_ _ gets called.
if i do s.bar(1) it's  _ _call_ _ that gets called, right? So, what causes _ _get_ _ to be called?

Comment: @pablowilks2 no, `__get__` gets called when you do `s.bar`, in which case, it returns `self` wrapped by `MethodType`, which essentially partially applies the `self` argument to `__call__`

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga so if I do s.bar(1), does ```__get__``` get called which in turn passes self to ```__call__``` which in turn, gets called?

Comment: @pablowilks2 basically, yes. Essentially, `s.bar` returns `MethodType(profiled_instance, instance_being_profiled)`, which basically partially applies `instance_being_profiled` to `profiled_instance`, so *then* `Profiled.__call__` gets called with `profiled_instance(instance_being_profiled, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, am i right then that 
when s.bar(1) is called, Python will retrieve the bar/Profiled function by invoking __get__ in Profiled?
 
In this particular case Profiled uses  __get__ to bind Profiled/bar to the instance (in this case s) and then returns Profiled/bar to Python. At which point Python calls Profiled.__call__  as a method of s?

Comment: Again, `Profiled.__get__` is called when `s.bar` is evaluated, you can think of `s.bar(1) -> methodobject(1)`, where `__get__` returns the method object. `s` gets bound to the `profiled_instance`, just like `s` would get bound to a regular method.